# Java generics clarification of a code snippet

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand this piece of Code. It is from [Oracle Generics Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html).

I am seeing two return types here `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and `int`. Am I reading this right ? If so how can a method have two return types ?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
    if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
        ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has only one return type: int.

`<T extends Comparable<T>>` is just to declare the type of T.

If you do something like this:

```
public static int calculate(T param) {
  ....
}
```

You would have a compilation error as T is undefined.
T is a generic type so you need to specify it:

```
public static <T> int calculate(T param) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: Is that only in static generic method case or just any generic method ?

Comment: No, that was a stupid question, any generic method should need parameter type declaration if a static method does, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, the return type is `int`

`T extends Comparable<T>` is *type parameter*, and used in the parameters.